# Percentile_Cont function throwing error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have this query where I am trying to introduce a non-static value into PERCENTILE_CONT:

```
SELECT perf2.REVIEW_PERIOD
     , PERCENTILE_CONT(goalsASP.GOAL*.01) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AVG_AMT ASC) ast75 
FROM repDB.TBL_PERFORMANCE perf2 JOIN
      pz.CATEGORY C on perf2.DEPTCAT = C.id JOIN
      repDB.TBL_GOALS_MATRIX goalsASP ON C.NAME = goalsASP.DIMENSION_Y
                                       and perf2.REVIEW_PERIOD = goalsASP.SNAP_NAME 
                                       and goalsASP.DIMENSION_X = 'asp'
GROUP BY perf2.REVIEW_PERIOD
```

The error thrown is:

`ORA-30497: Argument should be a constant or a function of expressions in GROUP BY.
30497. 00000 -  "Argument should be a constant or a function of expressions in GROUP BY."`

This is in a view, it was working fine when `goalsASP.GOAL*.01` was `.75` and I have a stored procedure where feeding a column as an argument works just fine so I'm kind of at a loss for what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.  It's not so much a problem of Percentile_Cont, it's a problem of correct grouping.

To troubleshoot I isolated `goalsASP.GOAL`

```
SELECT perf2.REVIEW_PERIOD
     , goalsASP.GOAL
FROM repDB.TBL_PERFORMANCE perf2 JOIN
      pz.CATEGORY C on perf2.DEPTCAT = C.id JOIN
      repDB.TBL_GOALS_MATRIX goalsASP ON C.NAME = goalsASP.DIMENSION_Y
                                       and perf2.REVIEW_PERIOD = goalsASP.SNAP_NAME 
                                       and goalsASP.DIMENSION_X = 'asp'
GROUP BY perf2.REVIEW_PERIOD
```

Then it became obvious that I needed to also group by `goalsASP.GOAL`.

So, then, the answer is:

```
SELECT perf2.REVIEW_PERIOD
     , PERCENTILE_CONT(goalsASP.GOAL*.01) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AVG_AMT ASC) ast75 
FROM repDB.TBL_PERFORMANCE perf2 JOIN
      pz.CATEGORY C on perf2.DEPTCAT = C.id JOIN
      repDB.TBL_GOALS_MATRIX goalsASP ON C.NAME = goalsASP.DIMENSION_Y
                                       and perf2.REVIEW_PERIOD = goalsASP.SNAP_NAME 
                                       and goalsASP.DIMENSION_X = 'asp'
GROUP BY perf2.REVIEW_PERIOD,
         goalsASP.GOAL
```

Kind of embarrassing that I didn't see that before, but tired eyes miss this stuff.